# ¿Cómo no repetir datos de una BBDD a través de PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relaciones

Resulta que tengo dos tablas, una de casas y otra de comentarios donde una casa puede tener varios comentarios como es lógico. El problema de novato que tengo es que al mostrar dichos datos como cada casa tiene varios comentarios me repite los datos. Es decir, si una casa tiene 3 comentarios esa casa me sale 3 veces, y quiero que solo me salga UNA VEZ.

Este es el código de la tabla que muestra los datos:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($opiniones as $opinion)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{{ route('opiniones.show',$opinion->casas_id) }}">
                    {{ $opinion->casas_id }}
                </a>
            </td>

            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{{ route('casa.show',$opinion->casas->ciudad) }}">
                    {{ $opinion->casas->ciudad }}
                </a> 
            </td>

            <td>{{$opinion->casas->precio}}</td>

            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{{ route('alquilers.show',$opinion->casas->alquilers->id) }}">
                    {{ $opinion->casas->alquilers->id }}
                </a>
            </td>
                           
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{{ route('opiniones.show',$opinion->casas_id) }}">
                    Ver comentarios
                </a>
            </td>
                
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

Luego ya he hecho que pinchando en un link de comentarios te muestre los comentarios, tenga 1 comentario, 2 o 25. Lo que quiero es que en esta vista no se repitan las casas, que como podéis ver si sale casas_id y esa casa tiene 3 comentarios me sale la ID de la misma casa 3 veces.

Un saludo y gracias.

Vista, como veis salen repetidas porque tienen mas de 1 comentario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El controller;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Hiciste las relaciones de tus modelos entre Casas y Comentarios? Porque eso se resuelve buscando en la tabla comentarios, donde el id de la casa sea igual al que buscas, entonces eso te trae todos los comentarios de esa casa solamente.

Comment: He puesto el mínimo código posible para no saturar, pero la relación entre tablas funciona, el código que he puesto funciona, es decir, me saca los datos. Pero como digo, si una casa tiene varios comentarios me saca por duplicado esa casa. Ese es el problema.

Comment: Por supuesto @BetaM, ya he añadido el ejemplo.

Comment: @BetaM, ¿a lo que acabo de añadir ahora te refieres?.

Comment: Discúlpame @BetaM. La última imagen es el controller de la tabla de opiniones, aunque desde la vista se ven datos de otras tablas exteriores como puedes ver en el primer código que puse. Pero las tablas foráneas que invoco  creo que no deberían afectar.

Comment: @BetaM está la tabla "casas" y está la tabla "opiniones", ambas se relacionan entre si por una relación de 1:N a través de la clave foránea "casas_id" que se encuentra en opiniones.

Comment: Del modo en que me lo has comentado no sale, porque no se puede ir desde casas hasta opiniones, debes ir de opiniones hasta casas. He probado con $opiniones = \App\opiniones::with('casas')->get(); y hasta con  $opiniones = \App\casas::all(); Sale la consulta pero sigue saliendo duplicado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De lo que se compartido en los comentarios rescatamos que:

- La relación es *uno a muchos*, donde una casa puede tener N opiniones
- De acuerdo con el planteamiento expuesto necesitas recuperar cada casa con sus respectivas opiniones asociadas

Luego de lo anterior, entonces:

1. No es conveniente que obtengas primero todas las opiniones pues te enfrentarías al [problema de **N+1**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)
2. La consulta debería partir del siguiente modo:

   ```
   Casa::with('opiniones')->get();
   ```

Como te mencionaba lo anterior te debería devolver:

1. Una colección principal con todas las casas
2. Por cada *objeto casa* una eventual colección con todas las opiniones que tiene asociadas
3. Ya solo te restaría iterar la data anterior para poder obtener la salida esperada

Notas:

- No conozco en detalle tus modelos y las relaciones definidas así que el ejemplo que propuse lo deberías ajustar
- Te restaría revisar si cumples con lass convenciones solicitadas o [debes hacer ajustes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)
- Ya si quieres ir un poco mas allá y asegurarte de solo obtener las casas que si tienen al menos una relación existente, recomiendo leas [justo aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: Conseguí arreglarlo, muchas gracias!

Comment: @adv recuerda si conseguiste la solución de otra forma, entonces te invito a publicarlo como respuesta y marcar esa como aceptada